# Crawler code run successfully locally in PyCharm, but have error in Notebook

Tags: python, web-crawler, kaggle

I just started learning crawler, and am practicing `requests.get()`, like

```
requests.get(url, headers={
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.80 Safari/537.36'
    })
```

For the same code that ran successfully in local Pycharm, if I run it in Kaggle Notebook, there will be an error message as below.

Error message:

> HTTPConnectionPool(host='movie.douban.com', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /top250/ (Caused by NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution',))

Could anyone tell me why is it, and how to fix it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: When you say you run it in `Kaggle Notebook` do you mean you run it on the same machine or through some sort of web GUI?

Comment: Yes, it's through a free GPU notebook like: https://www.kaggle.com/notebooks. Issue fixed - it's because we need to manually open the "internet connection" in that notebook. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Kaggle Notebooks won't allow internet connections unless you activate it.

You have to log in and set the internet activated in the right menu.

The process is described in this other question [kaggle kernels: urllib.request.urlopen not working for any url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48969283/kaggle-kernels-urllib-request-urlopen-not-working-for-any-url)